# Can I query elasticsearch with NEST for Time greather than 7:00

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I found this : https://discuss.elastic.co/t/hour-minute-date-format-in-range-queries/66299

```
    {
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "hour": {
                        "gte": "now",
                        "format": "HH:mm",
                        "include_lower": true,
                        "include_upper": true
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I dont know how to do it in NEST. I have column that have values like 13:00, 12:00, 6:00 etc. and I try to create query like this:

```
public void TestRequestToES()
    {
        NESTProvider es = new NESTProvider();
        TimeSpan span = TimeSpan.Parse("16:20");
        DateTime dt = DateTime.MinValue.Add(span);
        var client = es.GetCurrentContext();
        var result = client.Search<Workout>(s => s.Query(q => q.Bool( b=> b.Filter( bf => bf.DateRange(r => r.Field( f=> f.WorkoutStartTime).GreaterThanOrEquals(dt))))));
    }
```

but it dont works. Also I cant find any example for do that in NEST.

Comment: What doesn't work, what error if any you are getting? A bit more detail would help

Comment: Not error returned. But it don't find any result. Now I try something like this:
 var result = client.Search<Workout>(s => s.Query(q => q.DateRange( r => r.Field( f=> f.WorkoutStartTime).GreaterThanOrEquals("17:00").Format("hh:mm"))));
but it still dont work.

Comment: Please post a sample of your data and your index mapping